# How to deal with MQTT with a client and 2 servers replying to each other?

Tags: python, multithreading, mqtt

I need help understanding a mqtt case i'm trying to set up.
It is composed by 3 files, **control.py**, **server_a.py** and **server_b.py**.

For sake of simplicity, no ssl, so port 1883 is used and QoS is 2.
The whole thing is being supervised with [MQTT.fx](http://mqttfx.org).
Everything is running locally on a Mac OS X (Mosquitto server has been installed using brew)

Example has been mainly taken from book Hands-On MQTT Programming with Python written by Gaston C. Hillar. 
Modified code is [here](https://github.com/pilaurent/mqtt.git)

1. The general idea is to start an action from an IoT.
2. It will publish
   to a server A which is getting info from a database.
3. This server A will contact another one (let's say server B, within
   the loop) which will contact an external Web Service. (Sleep 1s)
4. Once its job
   done, server B will reply to server A which will have to update
   database in return.

control.py is publishing to `mqtt/listen/thingstodo/commands`

server_a.py is subscribing `mqtt/listen/thingstodo/#`.
    When work is done, server_a is publishing to `myapi/thingstodo/new/thingstodo/commands`

server_b.py is subscribing to `myapi/thingstodo/new/#` and when work is done,
            is publishing to `myapi/thingstodo/done/thingstodo/commands`

**This being written, here is my question :**

When I tried this code, if i change the number of loops to be done to 10, 50 and 100, it seems everything working fine under a certain number of actions, it's taking ages to have a job done message. For more than 50, some messages are not going back to server_A.

```
comments                mqtt/listen/thingstodo/#    myapi/thingstodo/new/#  myapi/thingstodo/done/#
10 things to do                    1                           10                      10
50 things to do                    1                           50                      41
100 things to do                   1                           100                     Never received (too long ?)
```

I presume this is due to a threading problem but i don't know how to resolve it.

Do i have to implement client.loop_start() and loop_stop() on server_A and B ? If positive, how do i do that properly ?

Regards,

Pierre

Comment: Using mqtt QoS 2 is the slowest way to send mqtt messages. Maybe try playing with the QoS level to 0 or 1 and see if that changes anything. Mosquito should definitely be able to handle thousands of requests to it with no problem. Check out this for more info about QoS https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/

Comment: I also have that book, but its unnecesarily complicated. You would do better to program both subscriber and publisher yourself. If you want I can give you my asyncrhonous subscriber and publisher so you can start off immediatly with testing

Comment: ty both for your help.tried with different qos but still the same. I'm sure I missed sth. Martin, any code would be much appreciated.